# Angular calendar custom event style

Tags: css, angular, calendar

I'm using angular calendar, and I want to customize the events style,for example- to change their shape to square instead of circle.
I tried this code:

```
 <mwl-calendar-month-view [eventTitleTemplate]="customEventsStyle" [locale]="locale" [viewDate]="viewDate" [events]="events" (dayClicked)="dayClicked($event.day)" (eventClicked)="eventClick($event)">
    {{ viewDate | calendarDate:(view + 'ViewTitle'):'Es' }}
  </mwl-calendar-month-view>

  <ng-template #customEventsStyle let-event="event">
    <div class="cal-events">
      <p style="background-color: brown;">{{event.title}}</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

But it didn't change anything in the style.
I also tried to change the css file in this path:
"../node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css"
I changed the style of the .cal-month-view .cal-event class, but nothing happend.

I'm new for this issue, I'll be thankful if you could help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found it out!
I just added this code into the custom template instead of the div:

```
  <ng-template #customCellTemplate let-day="day">
    <mat-list *ngFor="let e of day.events">
        <button class="customEvent" (click)="eventClick(e)">
          {{e.title}}
        </button>
    </mat-list>
  </ng-template>


<mwl-calendar-month-view [cellTemplate]="customCellTemplate"> ect...
```

Thanks